# git push - unbale to acess

Tags: git, github

Ao tentar realizar um git push para o github o mesmo me retorna o seguinte:
`git push fatal: unable to access https://github.com/renannasc/fsphpdeveloper.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com`

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro indica problema de conexão, pode ser causado por um antivírus que não seja o padrão fornecido pelo Windows, ou se você esta usando um servidor proxy para acessar a Internet, o Git requer uma configuração especial, pode ser também, uma regra de firewall, ou seja há várias coisas que podem estar causando esse problema.

Comment: A sim entendi muito obrigado!

Irei verificar